# my post doesn't insert in my database

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am creating a facebook like posting system..

My problem today is it doesn't seem to insert the value i get from the text area into my data base..

here is my java script:

```
$("#share").click(function()
    {
               //var typeNew = document.getElementById("content").value;
               var update = $( "textarea#content" ).val();
               //document.write(update);

                if(update.length == 0)
               {
                    alert("empty, please type something.");
                    //$(this).html('<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"1; URL=insert.php\">');
               }
               else
               {
                    //$("#flash").show();
                    $("#flash").html('<img src="loader.gif" />Loading Comment...').fadeIn("slow");

                    $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
             url: "post_update.php",
                         data: 'update=' + update,

                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                           $("#flash").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                           //alert("Successfully Inserted")
                           $("#flash").hide();
                           //$(this).html('<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"1; URL=insert.php\">');

                           });
                           }
                     });
                }
              return false;
          });
```

then here is my php code:

```
<?php


    $post=$_REQUEST['update'];
    $post=$_POST['update'];
    //echo '$post';

   @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'wall');

                            if(mysqli_connect_errno())
                        {
                echo "Error! Could not connect to database. Reset fields.";
                exit;
                }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts(update,date_posted) VALUES('$post',NOW())";
    $result = $db->query($sql);


    if($result){

    echo 'OK';
}
else{
        echo 'FAIL';
}

$db->close();
```

?>

can someone tell me what's wrong?
it worked well when the delete function was in error but now that it's functional my share function does not work..

Comment: did u try to print the fina insert query, to analyze values ?

Comment: [Bobby-Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would like to come and play…

Comment: sanitize your $post first before putting it to database.

Comment: Why do you have `$post=$_REQUEST['update'];` and right after that `$post=$_POST['update'];`? In Your example they do the same thing.

Comment: echo your query and if there is no issue in the query then use use mysql_real_escape with your post value

Comment: What does the PHP script return to you? OK, FAIL or an MySQL error? Do a `alert(msg)` in your success block.

Comment: @Arfeen how do i print the insert query?

Comment: @Raidohh it doesn't return anything..

Comment: @suffocationkills just echo  $sql variable

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code you have the following lines:

```
$post=$_REQUEST['update'];
$post=$_POST['update'];
```

You shouldn't have these both. In Your case, You actually need only the second one but for testing, try commenting it out leaving only the `$_REQUEST` line. Now you can pass parameters by GET too.

To see, if the query is correct, print it out too like this:

```
echo $sql = "INSERT INTO posts(update,date_posted) VALUES('$post',NOW())";
```

Now direct your browser to that location `your.domain/post_update.php?update=testmessage` and see the output.

If everything seems to be working, replace the POST/REQUEST lines with this:

```
$post=$db->real_escape_string($_POST["update"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this the other day.  Use autocommit or start and commit transactions.  Also, try a semicolon at the end of your statement (probably not the issue).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

If your $post is coming out to be fine then try:

```
$post = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["update"]); 
if (!db->query("INSERT INTO posts(update,date_posted) VALUES('$post' ,NOW())")) {
   echo $db->sqlstate; //show error
}
else {
  echo "inserted";
}
```

Comment: actually there's no error.. it just doesn't insert the value to the database.. @jerrymouse

Comment: Is the table engine innodb or myisam?

Comment: To find the engine type of your table posts type `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'posts'` in mysql prompt or use phpmyadmin and look under 'Type'

Comment: does this: echo $db->sqlstate; also not show anything, try alerting it in your ajax success function..!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column type of `update` is `varchar` / `char`and `date_posted` is `datetime`:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO posts(update,date_posted) VALUES('%s',NOW())",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($post));
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the column name "update" to anyother. it may works. And Avoid some predefined varibales for column names.

Hope it helps.